# Ruby on Rails - contact form is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed this website to do the contact form in my rails application. I am using a blank bootstrap template inside the rails application.

https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/rails-4-simple-form-and-mail-form-to-make-contact-form/

The only difference that I made is that in the contact.rb I added my email

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
attribute :name,      :validate => true
attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w] {2,})\z/i
attribute :message
attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true


def headers
{
  :subject => "My Contact Form",
  :to => "here I added my email",
  :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
}
end
end
```

When I run the local host, everything seems to work, even the message appears and it says that the email has been sent. However, when I check my email I don't find anything in the inbox.

Answer (score 1):

On development machines, the default setting in Rails is not to deliver mails, so you have to set `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries` to true.
Look here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration

Comment: is that the only thing I should add ? the code under 6.1 Example Action Mailer Configuration? because nothing changed when I did that

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code and also which email service you intend to use and how it's configured, so I cannot be sure. If you're a beginner, have a look at SendGrid's docs, they have a ruby gem that makes your life easier: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html

Comment: The code that I used is exactly same as what is written in this website

Comment: https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/rails-4-simple-form-and-mail-form-to-make-contact-form/

Comment: What you gave me has nothing to do with the contact form, it is about signing up